# ant matching anything after pattern?

Tags: spring-security, pattern-matching, hystrix, turbine

I have the following ant matching pattern:

```
http
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/proxy.stream*")
            .authenticated().and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/dashboard/login.html")
            .usernameParameter("userName")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard/index.html")
            .permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
```

It is not matching the following url because of the reserved character "?" in it. I wanna be able to match anything that comes after "proxy.stream".

```
https://example.com/proxy.stream?origin=https://example.com/turbine.stream?cluster
```

I have tried to url encode

> ?origin=https://example.com/turbine.stream?cluster

part of the url, but that gives me 400 bad request error in the browser.

How do i tell spring to match my url?

Comment: What's the 400 error message? Add the stacktrace, if any. Anyway if it did not matched with the url, the request would be handled normally by the controller, as if there were no security at all.

Comment: @Ali Dehghani: The 400 bad request error was given by chrome in chrome webconsole. There is no error stacktrace.

Comment: Check your IDE console, or tomcat/jetty log